# Will calling $.click() cause video.play() to be allowable by Webkit/IOS/Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, html5-video

I want to have a HTML5 `<video>` autoplay on Android and IOS browsers.

I cannot have the user do a button click, however my interaction flow is this:

1. The user enters the video playing page by pressing a submit button on a form.
2. Then the user waits for the video to start playing when a program on the server tells it to (checked via AJAX).
3. The video should autoplay at this point.

This is ethical because in step 1 there is user interaction. However, [webkit](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) states that:

> A note about the user gesture requirement: when we say that an action must have happened “as a result of a user gesture”, we mean that the JavaScript which resulted in the call to video.play(), for example, must have **directly resulted from a handler** for a touchend, click, doubleclick, or keydown event.

In my application, the video autoplay is not directly triggered by the button click, but it is an AJAX success handler.

I could change my approach here and have AJAX tell the script how many seconds before starting and wait with a `Promise`, but that may lock up the user interface, if I'm not mistaken. This way, the call to `play()` would be inside the click event handler.

I could write an click event handler:

```js
<video id="video" src="video.mp4">Browser Unsupported</video>
<button id="button" style="display:none>invisible</button>
<script>
$('#button').click(function() {
    $("#video").get(0).play();
});

// Then click the invisible button...

$("#button").click();
```

But I'm not sure if this will work because the click event is not genuine.

Will the above code example work to play the video automatically on Ios and bandroid devices, or is there another way?